# How to load scanpy generated h5ad file in R?

Tags: r

I am trying to read h5ad file in R, which was created using python scanpy.
However, I am getting this error:

```
Error in checkForRemoteErrors(lapply(cl, recvResult)) : 
  one node produced an error: AnnDataReadError: Above error raised while reading key '/layers' of type <class 'h5py._hl.group.Group'> from /. 
Detailed traceback:
  File "/Users/newuser/Library/Caches/org.R-project.R/R/basilisk/1.6.0/zellkonverter/1.4.0/zellkonverterAnnDataEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/anndata/_io/h5ad.py", line 421, in read_h5ad
    d[k] = read_attribute(f[k])
  File "/Users/newuser/Library/Caches/org.R-project.R/R/basilisk/1.6.0/zellkonverter/1.4.0/zellkonverterAnnDataEnv/lib/python3.7/functools.py", line 840, in wrapper
    return dispatch(args[0].__class__)(*args, **kw)
  File "/Users/newuser/Library/Caches/org.R-project.R/R/basilisk/1.6.0/zellkonverter/1.4.0/zellkonverterAnnDataEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/anndata/_io/utils.py", line 184, in func_wrapper
    f"Above error raised while reading key {elem.name!r} of "*
```

Code line I used is:

```
S <- readH5AD('cd10pos.h5ad')
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `anndata` package: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/anndata/versions/0.7.5.3/topics/read_h5ad

```
ad <- anndata::read_h5ad('cd10pos.h5ad')
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `SeuratDisk`.

Official tutorial:
https://mojaveazure.github.io/seurat-disk/articles/convert-anndata.html

Example:
https://github.com/satijalab/seurat/issues/3414#issuecomment-738941685

```
library(SeuratDisk)
Convert("cd10pos.h5ad", ".h5seurat")
seuratObj <- LoadH5Seurat("cd10pos.h5Seurat")
```